# Python: match/case by type of value

Tags: python, python-3.10

I came across a weird issue while using the new `match`/`case` syntax in Python3.10. The following example seems like it should work, but throws an error:

```py
values = [
    1,
    "hello",
    True
]

for v in values:
    match type(v):
        case str:
            print("It is a string!")
        case int:
            print("It is an integer!")
        case bool:
            print("It is a boolean!")
        case _:
            print(f"It is a {type(v)}!")
```

```sh
$ python example.py
  File "/.../example.py", line 9
    case str:
         ^^^
SyntaxError: name capture 'str' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

- It is mentioning that the first case (the value `str`) will always result in `True`.

---

Wondering if there is an alternative to this other than converting the type to a string.

Comment: `case` is followed by a pattern. Identifiers in patterns are variables that will be assigned from the corresponding part of the matching value, not they're not variables that are evaluated.

Comment: So `case str:` means that if the value is a single value, assign the value to `str` and execute that case body. It doesn't mean `if type(v) == str:`

Comment: You seem to be confusing this with `switch/case` from PHP or JavaScript.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Rather than match `type(v)`, match `v` directly:

```
values = [
    1,
    "hello",
    True,
]

for v in values:
    match v:
        case str():
            print("It is a string!")
        case bool():
            print("It is a boolean!")
        case int():
            print("It is an integer!")
        case _:
            print(f"It is a {type(v)}!")
```

Note that I've swapped the order of `bool()` and `int()` here, so that `True` being an instance of `int` doesn't cause issues.

This is a [class pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-patterns) match.

Comment: what about performance of instantiating new object for simple comparison?

Comment: @iperov Type matching in case does not actually instantiate a new object. You can see this for yourself by defining a custom type and putting a print in the init - it won't be called.

Comment: This fails for numpy integer types.

Comment: @Soren Can not reproduce. Could you show an example?

Comment: take `numpy.int64(1)` as input

Comment: @Soren  I have tried, it all works normally for me. Note that `isinstance(np.int64(1), int)` is False, and numpy ints are not a subclass of `int`. Did you expect otherwise? Another case statement, or adding a union to the existing `case int()`, would be needed to also catch numpy dtypes (which are a different type entirely). Maybe I'm misunderstanding what failure you mean..

Comment: Why would `True` being an instance of `int` cause an issues otherwise? Isn't the order of the cases supposed to be irrelevant?

Comment: Also, doesn't `str()` create an empty string? Or what is going on here? I thought a `match`–`case` statement compared the value of the expression after `match` with the values of the expressions after each `case`.

Comment: The order of the cases is not irrelevant, they are checked in order with first match winning. The `str()` in a `case` block is part of the [class pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#class-patterns) syntax, it is not an expression. Without the parens, it would be a name capture (rebinding the name `str`!)

Answer (score 2):

You can match directly against the type of `v`, but you need a *value* pattern to refer to the types to match, as a "dotless" name is a capture pattern that matches *any* value. For example,

```
values = [
    1,
    "hello",
    True
]

for v in values:
    match type(v):
        case __builtins__.str:
            print("It is a string!")
        case __builtins__.int:
            print("It is an integer!")
        case __builtins__.bool:
            print("It is a boolean!")
        case _:
            print(f"It is a {type(v)}!")
```

Note that a value pattern must be a dotted name; it's not an arbitrary expression that can evaluate to a specific value.

(Whether you really want to match against the actual type of a value, or really want to determine if a value is an *instance of* a given type, is another matter. In the latter case, an `if-elif` statement is needed.

```
if isinstance(v, bool):
    print("It is a boolean!")
elif isinstance(v, int):
    print("It is an int!")
elif isinstance(v, str):
    print("It is a string!")
else:
    print(f"It is a {type(v)}!")
```

There is no pattern that lets you use the result of calling `isinstance` as the case to match against.
)

Comment: Even though this might look uglier, I prefer it, as it does not involve as much "magic" as the officially accepted answer.  The class pattern syntax adds some heavy cognitive load, IMHO, for something that is rarely used.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Beware - they are logically different. Chepner's answer will match only the types _exactly_. The accepted answer will match with subtypes.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I played around with this some more after looking at it and, unfortunately, the official manner which Chepner recommends is better.  I just don't like introducing new syntax. (Nor do I like that Python allows for `str` to be treated like a variable, so that I can do things like `str = 7; str / 2` and get `3.5` back. Ack!!)

Comment: Not that I shadow builtins like `str` very often (there are usually better names to describe what the variable is doing), but doing so isn't the program-killing catastrophe some people make it out to be. Worst case, if you did decide to use `str` then realize later you need a reference to the built-in type, you can always use `builtins.str`.

Answer (score -3):

quotation marks

values = [
False,
"hello",
True
]

for v in values:
match type(v):
case 'str':
print("It is a string!")
case 'int':
print("It is an integer!")
case 'bool':
print("It is a boolean!")
case _:
print(f"It is a {type(v)}!")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not work.